# MySQL - GROUP BY changes results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Please help me explain why adding a GROUP BY clause changes the query's results. All else staying the same, removing the GROUP BY clause will produce a different result than adding the GROUP BY clause.

It would seem to me that a GROUP BY would simply group the results by a field, not alter the count.

I need to organize the data by table2.name, and get a count for each

```
SELECT table2.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(op.id))
FROM op INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.EID = op.ID
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table1.jobid
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table3.CatID
WHERE op.ActiveStartDate <= NOW()
    AND op.ActiveEndDate >= NOW()
GROUP BY table2.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: We cannot predict what do you see, please share the both query results

Comment: Strangeness is query works without GROUP BY (because MySql applies an implicit LIMIT 1 for all scalar fields not included in GROUP BY clause)

Comment: All aggregate functions (like `count`) calculate based on the record for a group if defined. Otherwise they base their calculations on the complete resultset.

Comment: The result with the GROUP BY is 350. The result without the GROUP BY is 150. 
@juergen..makes sense, but how do I fix it as I'm trying to get the results groups?

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` is an aggregate function, which, like other aggregate functions such `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` etc. are applied to each element within the group.

MySql is a bit more flexible than other DBs in the sense that it allows you to use `COUNT(*)` without a `GROUP BY`: this is not allowed in e.g. SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: What would be a better way to write the query then?

Comment: I would personally write it that way as it is more declarative and consistent with other SQL dialects.

Comment: Sorry, what way? The way I have it produces the wrong result. If I use COUNT(*) the result is also wrong. If I use COUNT(*) without GROUP BY the result is also wrong.

Comment: Write it with COUNT + GROUP BY: But from your post above I dont know what result you're looking for: count of table2 alone, or of non-distinct op.id.....?

Comment: I'm looking for the COUNT of distinct op.ID that have the attribute/fall under the category of table2.name. "COUNT + GROUP BY", isn't this how I have it already?

Comment: Yes, but if the answer is not what you expect then some information is missing e.g. what about NULLs in ActiveStartDate or in one of the columns xou use in the join?

Comment: Good point, but no, none of the columns joined are NULL (all required).

Answer (score 0):

This is because all GROUP BY actions are applied before any ORDER BY actions. However in the case above you have a grouping function in the ORDER clause. This means that there are actually 3 groupings being applied before the ORDER BY of the resulting data set:

- COUNT(DISTINCT(op.id))
- GROUP BY table2.name
- COUNT(*)

Sadly I don't know enough about the inner workings of MySQL to know why this has the exact effect that it does, but I do know how to fix it.

The solution is a sub SELECT i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        table2.name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(op.id)),
        COUNT(*) as c
    FROM op 
        JOIN table1 ON table1.EID = op.ID
        JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table1.jobid
        JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table3.CatID
    WHERE
        op.ActiveStartDate <= NOW()
        AND op.ActiveEndDate >= NOW()
    GROUP BY
        table2.name
) AS t
ORDER BY
    t.c DESC
```

Hopefully this wont make the query too slow!